# Terraform not detecting imported Azure SQL Server administrator_login_password

Tags: sql-server, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have defined an Azure SQL Server as:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "azure-sql-server" {
  name                         = "xxxxx"
  resource_group_name          = "xxxx"
  location                     = "xxxx"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "admin_login"
  administrator_login_password = "password"

}
```

Because the resource already exists in my Azure subscription, I had it imported with the `terraform import` command, which worked.

When I `terraform plan`, terraform says that the `administrator_login_password` will be updated in-place even though I have used the same password that is set in the Server.

How do I avoid it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `terraform import` to read the current resource into the state, the password will not be retrieved. This is because the Azure API (and most others) will not support reading the password from its relevant endpoint for security reasons. Therefore, the password is currently unknown in the state, and the Terraform Azure provider will attempt to update it.

You can prevent this with a `lifecycle` meta-block `ignore_changes` meta-argument targeting the `password` argument:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "azure-sql-server" {
  name                         = "xxxxx"
  resource_group_name          = "xxxx"
  location                     = "xxxx"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "admin_login"
  administrator_login_password = "password"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [administrator_login_password]
  }
}
```

and the Azure provider will no longer attempt an update operation against your resource. Relevant doc for `ignore_changes` is [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes).